# Why doesn't voice.exe detect my installed voices?

Tags: windows-10, voice, voice-command

I've found and installed this [command line text to speech](https://elifulkerson.com/projects/commandline-text-to-speech.php) project.

In Windows 10, I have gone to "Speech settings", and under "Installed voice packages", I installed a non-English voice package. Then rebooted, as the instructions said. The new "voice package" is listed in that GUI window, so it's definitely installed.

But `voice.exe -l` doesn't list it! See:

```
"Microsoft Hazel Desktop" - Adult,Female,en-GB
"eSpeak-en+f2" - Adult,Male,en-US
"eSpeak-en-us" - Adult,Male,en-US
"eSpeak-en" - Adult,Male,en-US
"Microsoft Zira Desktop" - Adult,Female,en-US
```

As you can see, there's just the useless "eSpeak" voices (all sound the same, like a robot) and the **English** Microsoft voices.

The non-English Microsoft voice package is not seen by `voice.exe`.

All I want is to be able to make my Windows 10 speak to me with a non-robotic voice, on the command line, with my native language. Why doesn't `voice.exe` see the proper voices? The English voices sound bizarre when trying to speak my language.

PS: I've now spent 15 minutes trying to get StackExchange to recognize the linebreaks in the above output dump. I now give up. I have linebreaks. I can't help if it doesn't care about them.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't voice.exe see the proper voices?

Only a subset of all the Microsoft voices available in Windows are made available system-wide (i.e. to third-party applications). The majority of them are restricted to internal "Windows-only" use. The basic solution to this issue is to modify the registry to make these voices available to other applications.

There are a number of tutorials on the web detailing how to (potentially) unlock these voices for use by third-party software, such as [this one](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/08/11/unlock-all-windows-10-tts-voices-system-wide-to-get-more-of-them/) on the broad steps for any voice and [this one](https://windowsreport.com/unlock-new-text-to-speech-voice-windows-10/) for Eva (Cortana) specifically. However, be aware that Windows 10 is "fluid" and the exact steps may be different for different versions of the operating system.

---

*It's also probably worth mentioning that there could (theoretically) be technical compatibility issues depending on how the third-party software implements its TTS interface (e.g. what API it uses,etc.).*

---